# is there any replacement class of WebSocketServerFactory in jetty 10?

Tags: jetty

Jetty 9 has WebSocketServerFactory class but in jetty 10 there is no such class present.
What is the alternative way without using WebSocketServerFactory?

Below factory class created in jetty 9. Now I want to upgrade to jetty 10 but facing difficulties. any suggestions please!!

```
public class UpgradeSocketServerFactory extends WebSocketServerFactory
{
    private static final Executor executor = CustomExecutors.newFabricCachedThreadPool(10, "jetty-threads");
    private static final ByteBufferPool bufferPool = new ArrayByteBufferPool(0, 0, 64*1024);

    public UpgradeSocketServerFactory(WebSocketPolicy policy)
    {
        super(policy, executor, bufferPool);

    }

    @Override
    public Object createWebSocket(ServletUpgradeRequest req, ServletUpgradeResponse resp)
    {
        return new sendCustomObject();
    }
    
}
```

Note: UpgradeSocketServerFactory Contractor calling from other class.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question was unclear about the struggles you are having, I'll just assume it's the `createWebSocket()` method.  If this is not the case, use the *Question* section at the official issue tracker to have a conversation about your struggles (stackoverflow is for narrow focused and specific development questions)

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/new/choose

The `WebSocketCreator` is still there, that's how you should be using the `WebSocketServletFactory` and/or `WebSocketServerFactory`.

Steps to take:

1. change your Jetty 9 code to NOT extend from `WebSocketServerFactory`
2. use `WebSocketCreator` instead to create a custom websocket instance of your endpoint
3. register your `WebSocketCreator` by mapping it to a URL pathSpec.
4. Use the `NativeWebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configure()` in your embedded code to do that.

See: https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-websocket-examples/blob/9.4.x/native-jetty-websocket-example/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/EventServer.java

*Jetty 9 technique*

```java
        // Setup the basic application "context" for this application at "/"
        // This is also known as the handler tree (in jetty speak)
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");
        server.setHandler(context);

        // Configure specific websocket behavior
        NativeWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.configure(context,
            (servletContext, nativeWebSocketConfiguration) ->
            {
                // Configure default max size
                nativeWebSocketConfiguration.getPolicy().setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(65535);

                // Add websockets
                nativeWebSocketConfiguration.addMapping("/events/*", new EventEndpointCreator());
            });

        // Add generic filter that will accept WebSocket upgrade.
        WebSocketUpgradeFilter.configure(context);
```

Now, time to upgrade to Jetty 10/11.

1. Change name of `WebSocketCreator` to `JettyWebSocketCreator`
2. You'll use `JettyWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.configure()` instead.

See: https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-websocket-examples/blob/11.0.x/native-jetty-websocket-example/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/demo/EventServer.java

*Jetty 11 technique*

```java
        // Setup the basic application "context" for this application at "/"
        // This is also known as the handler tree (in jetty speak)
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");
        server.setHandler(context);

        // Configure specific websocket behavior
        JettyWebSocketServletContainerInitializer.configure(context, (servletContext, wsContainer) ->
        {
            // Configure default max size
            wsContainer.setMaxTextMessageSize(65535);

            // Add websockets
            wsContainer.addMapping("/events/*", new EventEndpointCreator());
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Joakim Erdfelt. How to pass executor object?